# Shoud the Spring request mapping logic map to a handler method based upon the value of servletPath?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Apologies if this has been asked before. I have searched the Spring docs, on StackOverflow, and the Web in general but haven't managed to find an answer.

I'm fairly new to Spring, and in the process of investigating a request mapping issue that I was having, I came across some unusual and unexpected (to me) behaviour which causes a single `<url-pattern>` and `@RequestMapping` to be invoked from 2 different URLs.
I'm sure it's down to a lack of understanding on my part so I'm hoping that someone can confirm how it should behave, and preferably point me to where it is documented. I'm using the Spring Framework via a standalone Servlet Container, rather than SpringBoot.

The following example illustrates the behaviour.

Consider the following web.xml snippet

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>TestSpringServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/test-spring-servlet-config.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>TestSpringServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test-servlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

deployed at a context path of:

`/apps`

test-spring-servlet-config.xml contains:

```
<beans>
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <bean id="TestController" class="org.example.TestSpringServletController" />
</beans>
```

The TestSpringServletController class is defined as:

```
@Controller
public class TestSpringServletController
{
  @GetMapping("/test-servlet")
  public void testAll(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
  {
    response.getWriter().append("<h2>Spring Test Servlet - testAll()</h2>");
    response.getWriter().append("ContextPath: [").append(request.getContextPath()).append("]<br/>");
    response.getWriter().append("ServletPath: [").append(request.getServletPath()).append("]<br/>");
    response.getWriter().append("PathInfo: [").append(request.getPathInfo()).append("]");
  }


  @GetMapping("/test-servlet/{id}")
  public void testWithId(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String id) throws IOException
  {
    response.getWriter().append("<h2>Spring Test Servlet - testWithId()</h2>");
    response.getWriter().append("ContextPath: [").append(request.getContextPath()).append("]<br/>");
    response.getWriter().append("ServletPath: [").append(request.getServletPath()).append("]<br/>");
    response.getWriter().append("PathInfo: [").append(request.getPathInfo()).append("]");
  }
}
```

accessing:
`http://localhost:8084/apps/test-servlet/test-servlet`
results in:

```
Spring Test Servlet - testAll()
ContextPath: [/apps]
ServletPath: [/test-servlet]
PathInfo: [/test-servlet]
```

As expected.

Accessing:

`http://localhost:8084/apps/test-servlet/test-servlet/myid`
results in:

```
Spring Test Servlet - testWithId()
ContextPath: [/apps]
ServletPath: [/test-servlet]
PathInfo: [/test-servlet/myid]
```

Also as expected.

However, accessing:
`http://localhost:8084/apps/test-servlet`
results in:

```
Spring Test Servlet - testAll()
ContextPath: [/apps]
ServletPath: [/test-servlet]
PathInfo: [null]
```

This was not what I was expecting and I can't find this behaviour documented. I would expect a 404 Not Found error. What I assume is happening is that when PathInfo is null, the Spring Request Mapper is using the ServletPath instead. However, when PathInfo is not null then just the PathInfo value is used, as demonstrated by:
`http://localhost:8084/apps/test-servlet/myid`
which results in:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /apps/test-servlet/myid. Reason: Not Found
```

I'm actually sure I've read somewhere that servletPath shouldn't be used by a servlet as part of the request, but can't find that particular reference at the moment.

Changing the @GetMapping to "/" for testAll() and "/{id}" for testWithId() doesn't have the desired effect either, as accessing:
`http://localhost:8084/apps/test-servlet`
now results in a call to testWithId() rather than testAll(), which now needs a trailing / in it's URL in order to function as it did before without the trailing /. To be honest, this isn't what I had anticipated either, and looks to be another case where the Spring request mapper has used the servletPath in place of the PathInfo (which is null without the trailing space). If anyone can shed light on this I would also be grateful.

One way I have found to avoid the issue is by changing the url-pattern (and hence the servletPath) or changing the PathInfo in order to make the values different. That seems to be an odd constraint (and closely couples a deploy time configuration with a compile time configuration) and I haven't seen in mentioned anywhere.

Any information or pointers that anyone can provide on either of these behaviors would be gratefully received. Apologies for such a long winded question!

Regards

====

Quick update in response to the initial comments below:

Replacing web.xml with:

```
public class WebAppBootstrap implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
  private static final String URI_TEST_SERVICE = "/test-servlet/*";
  private static final String NAME_TEST_SERVICE = "TestSpringServlet";

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
  {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext testServletContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    testServletContext.register(TestServletConfig.class);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic testDispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(NAME_TEST_SERVICE, new DispatcherServlet(testServletContext));
    testDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    testDispatcher.addMapping(URI_TEST_SERVICE);
  }
}
```

and `test-spring-servlet-config.xml` with:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class TestServletConfig
{
  @Bean
  public TestSpringServletController testController()
  {
    return new TestSpringServletController();
  }
}
```

makes no difference whatsoever to the observed behaviour.

Comment: Is this for a new application or a legacy one? The modern style is to eliminate all of the `web.xml` business and use Spring Boot. (And in either case, you should try hard to avoid using `HttpServletR*` directly; the point of Spring is that the MVC infrastructure handles all the mapping and binding for you.)

Comment: It is for a new application. While the actual application is still Spring Framework rather than Spring Boot, it doesn’t use HttpServletR* or web.xml. The example above was just to illustrate the issue I was seeing with minimal code in a simple test Servlet, and provide easy access to the request URL fields for the debug output.

Comment: Removed the logging lines from the example code to make it more concise as the same details are in the response output

Comment: If your "actual application" doesn't use `web.xml`, then the example is so far removed as to be useless for helping you debug a path problem.

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying however, the example exhibits the behaviour that I am trying to resolve and is therefore perfectly adequate for the question I have raised, which is basically why does Spring behave as it does with the example code provided.

Comment: As per the above comments, I have removed web.xml and the Spring xml configuration, and replaced them with code based configuration alternatives (relevant code is added to the question text). This has made no difference to the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Having taken a look at the Spring source code it would appear that the above behaviour is somewhat by design (although maybe the particular use case above isn't).

When determining the path to use when performing a lookup for a matching handler method, a call is made to: `UrlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(HttpServletRequest request)`

This method first checks whether `alwaysUseFullPath` is set to `true`. If it is then it uses both the servlet path and the path info as the lookup path.

If `alwaysUseFullPath` is set to `false` then it attempts to construct a lookup path using just the path info (as you would expect). However, if the path found is an empty string then it falls back to using both the servlet path and the path info i.e. as if `alwaysUseFullPath` was set to `true`.

So, the result is that both the URI's `/apps/test-servlet/test-servlet` and `/apps/test-servlet` result in a lookup path of `/test-servlet` and will therefore both match against the `@GetMapping` value for `testAll()`.

It's a shame there isn't a `neverUseFullPath` setting as I don't think the behaviour I have observed is desirable, even if it might not be that likely (although if a different team is responsible for coding the servlet and deploying the servlet then maybe you could get the duplication within the URI).